# VBA Compile error: syntax error in code- How can i fix this?

Tags: vba

I keep getting "Compile error: syntax error" when I try to run this code in VBA:

```vb
Sub Quantity_sold()
    
    Dim sales As Range
    Dim sold As Double
    Dim lastrow As Integer, lastcol As Long
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
   
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 1 To lastcol
        For n = 1 To lastrow
            If Cells(n, i).Value >= sold Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next n
        
    ' ### Error occurs in the following line ###
    If MsgBox("Sales Were above, etc... (This will take a moment" ).", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
        count = count + 1
        MsgBox "You pressed cancel"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Next i
        
End Sub
```

Comment: What looks off to you about `"Sales Were above, etc... (This will take a moment" )."`? Hint: quotes.

Comment: The syntax highlighting pretty much already shows you.

Comment: The quote outside the parenthesis looks off. But if i take it out, it brings another error message.

Comment: Close, but no cigar - try that again. It was half right.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the " after moment and it works OK.

```
Sub Quantity_sold()
    
    Dim sales As Range
    Dim sold As Double
    Dim lastrow As Integer, lastcol As Long
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
   
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 1 To lastcol
        For n = 1 To lastrow
            If Cells(n, i).Value >= sold Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next n
        
    ' ### Error occurs in the following line ### when there was a " after moment
    If MsgBox("Sales Were above, etc... (This will take a moment ).", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
        count = count + 1
        MsgBox "You pressed cancel"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Next i
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like " is causing the error. look at this line (This will take a moment" )